# Как использовать вычисляемое значение в другом месте sql-запроса?

Tags: sql, select

Есть в таблице поле, которое содержит значение оклада (тип nvarchar(10), не я делал).
Нужно, чтобы запрос выводил премию и суммарно оклад и премию. Ниже пример вычисляемой премии.

```
declare @temp_table table (
    user_salary nvarchar(10)
    )

insert into @temp_table (user_salary) values ('')
insert into @temp_table (user_salary) values (NULL)
insert into @temp_table (user_salary) values ('123')

select (convert(float,isnull((case user_salary when '' then 0 
                                else user_salary
                                end),0))/2) as [prem]
from @temp_table
```

Возможно ли использование в дальнейшем данного вычисляемого значения или придется дублировать код?

**UPD.** Подразумевается, что по итогу запроса должно выводиться и оклад, и премия, и их общая сумма.

Comment: А что вы понимаете под "вычисляемым значением": `float` из выражения или результат запроса?

Comment: Вы можете обернуть это в еще один select и использовать вычисленное значение. т.е. `select prem, perm + oklad from (ваш запрос) A`

Comment: @Mirdin результат, который получится в колонке prem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете заключить свой запрос еще в один select и на верхнем уровне вычисленные колонки будут доступны для любой работы с ними:

```
select [prem], [prem]+...
  from (
    select user_salary, (convert(float,isnull((case user_salary when '' then 0 
                                else user_salary
                                end),0))/2) as [prem]
      from @temp_table
  ) A
```

Comment: спасибо. То, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [SQL block](http://ivan-shamaev.ru/pl_sql_functions_procedures_variables_cursors_cycles/). В нём возможно использование переменных и их подстановка в запросы.

Comment: А какое отношение pl/sql имеет к вопросу по ms sql server (хотя это конечно догадка, автор не указал, но такое объявление временных таблиц на это явно указывает)

Comment: а какое отношение ms sql сервер имеет к вопросу?

Comment: Можем уточнить у автора конечно, но он использует у себя declare table и таблица с собакой и заключение имен колонок в квадратные скобки, такой синтаксис только в ms sql (ну возможно еще в sybase от которого ms sql произошел)

Comment: Я понюду, мона? Автор просил, "как в sql", я ответил, как в sql. Если автору нужен ms sql - он уточнит, но следующий, кто найдет этот вопрос поиском - увидит ответ "как в sql". А не только как в ms.

Comment: И кстати, сообщество не приветствует когда вся суть ответа содержится по ссылке, потому как ссылка может оказаться не рабочей. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Вы кстати ответили как в pl/sql, который используется только в двух БД: Oracle и postgres, так что чистым sql решением это нельзя назвать. И я кстати не понял, как это можно делать в блоке. вернее делать то можно, только Oracle не позволяет вернуть от туда набор данных ...

Answer (score 0):

вы можете объявить еще одну переменную, и присвоеть ей значение вашего выражение в запросе, и дальше работать с ней

`DECLARE @x  float;
select @x = (convert(float,isnull((case user_salary when '' then 0 
                                else user_salary
                                end),0))/2) as [prem]
from @temp_table`

Comment: Можно работать в том же запросе, т.е. написать `select @x=..., @x+column2 from ... where @x>100` ? (мне кажется автор вопроса это имел ввиду)

Comment: @Mike прошу прощения - да, я это имел ввиду. Т.е. в одном запросе вывести оклад, премию и общую сумму.